# How does implicit passing of object reference work?

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript code which works fine so far but I do not understand the how the variable "me" is set in the function "run"?

```
GameLoop.prototype.run = function() {

this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
var currentTimeMillis = this.startTime;
var loops;
var interpolation=0.0;
this.running=true;

return function(me){
    loops = 0;
    while (new Date().getTime() > currentTimeMillis && loops < me.MAX_FRAMESKIP) {
        me.updateGame();
        currentTimeMillis += me.SKIP_TICKS;
        loops++;
    }
    interpolation = parseFloat(new Date().getTime() + me.SKIP_TICKS - currentTimeMillis) / parseFloat(me.SKIP_TICKS);
    me.drawGame(interpolation);
}
```

}

The function is called continuously by the browser's animate function below. Since I do not pass any reference to the call f.run(), i guess the correct reference to me is set implicitly. Can someone explain me or give me some useful links which explains this behaviour?

```
GameLoop.prototype.recursiveAnim = function() {
        var f = this.run();
        f.run();
        this.animFrame( this.recursiveAnim );
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `run` you get a function in return, that function has one parameter and its called `me`.

For example

```
var x = function () { return function (me) { return me; } }
// by calling x, you get the function: `function (me) { return me; }
var f = x();
console.log(f(1)); // answer is 1
```

Comment: Wow. Thx for fast reply :). I understand what you stated but in my case f.run(); is called without passing any parameter. I do not understand why me references to this of the GameLoop object? In your case you pass the value me ( f(1)...but i have f.run())

Comment: `f` is a function in your case, which doesn't have the property `run`. You should double check your code for things you may have forgotten to post.

Comment: oh damn...you were right. I oversaw where I pass it...oh :D....sometimes someone has to tell you the obvious :D.....so problem solved. Thank you. I never use the recursiveAnim function ....ups :)